# Large sqlite database take long time to load in Android Delphi XE7

Tags: sqlite, delphi, load

I use Delphi XE7 TSQLConnection to connect to large SQLite database and deploy it on android, it works, but when i start the my app on android it take longtime to load, how can i shorten the loading time

The database has 3 field number, text, text contain about 28,000 records

here is my code and screen

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, Data.DbxSqlite,
  Data.FMTBcd, Fmx.Bind.Grid, System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs,
  Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt, Data.Bind.Controls,
  FMX.Layouts, Fmx.Bind.Navigator, Data.Bind.Components, FMX.Memo, FMX.Grid,
  Data.Bind.Grid, Data.Bind.DBScope, Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr, Datasnap.DBClient,
  Datasnap.Provider, System.IOUtils, FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView,
  FMX.MultiView;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    XxxConnection: TSQLConnection;
    TabledictTable: TSQLDataSet;
    TabledictTableIDCount: TWideMemoField;
    TabledictTableEnglish: TWideMemoField;
    TabledictTableRes: TWideMemoField;
    DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider;
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB;
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    MultiView1: TMultiView;
    ListView1: TListView;
    LinkListControlToField1: TLinkListControlToField;
    MemoRes: TMemo;
    LinkControlToFieldRes2: TLinkControlToField;
    procedure XxxConnectionBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiTb.fmx ANDROID}

procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
     xxxConnection.Open;
end;


procedure TForm3.XxxConnectionBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IF DEFINED(IOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  xxxConnection.Params.Values['Database'] :=
        TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath,'external/dictlao1.sdb.db')  { External }
  {$ENDIF}


end;

end.
```

[screen shot of Delphi form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ZXS.png)
[screen shot of database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Mjm.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: As already said, please provide some code, show the output you get and the expected one. This will help others to understand your problem and see how they can help :)

Comment: Opening a SQLite3 database is almost instant, even if it has a huge size. At opening, it only read a few pages. So IMHO there is something wrong with your code using the SQlite3 database: what do you call "load"? Certainly you are making a huge SELECT, or an unoptimized SELECT.